# Elevating NodeJS permissions

Tags: javascript, node.js, permissions

I am not sure how you would go about elevating NodeJs' permissions on the fly, the only way seems to be to run the whole program as root / admin.

Is there a way to elevate permissions on the fly (preferably dependency free and cross platform) ?

I've tried running a childProcess with `sudo` prefixed to the linux equivalent command of the node action (`writeFile()`), but even that didn't work out ...

---

The concrete problem:

I am trying to write to the hosts file, but I can't without admin privileges - Hence why I tried elevating the privileges.

Comment: Couldn't you start another process which runs under root and which only takes new host entries over some communication channel and writes them into the hosts file? That way you avoid running the whole thing as root.

Comment: A child of a non-elevated process probably can't run at an elevated privilege.

Comment: @JonasWilms `I've tried running a childProcess with sudo prefixed` => doesn't work, it doesn't ever prompt for a password.